# Objective C animates wrong button when scrolling in tablview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (IBAction)playShout:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;


    CGPoint point = [sender.superview convertPoint:sender.frame.origin toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = self.tempIndexPath;//[self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];


    DisplayPersonTableViewCell * cell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton * button=cell.playButton;

     self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    PFObject * shoutToPlay=[self.shoutsArrayForUserBeingDisplayed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [shoutToPlay fetchIfNeeded];
     [AnimationViewController endCircleAnimation];

    NSData * audioData=[self.audioDataDict objectForKey:shoutToPlay.objectId];





    if (player.playing)    {
        if(player.data==audioData)    {


            [player stop];
            [AnimationViewController endCircleAnimation];

        } else{

            [self setAllTableViewCellsToPlayButton];
            [AnimationViewController endCircleAnimation];


            sender.layer.cornerRadius=sender.frame.size.width/2;

            player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:audioData error:nil];
            player.delegate=self;
            [player prepareToPlay];
            if (DISPLAY_IS_MUTED)  {
                player.volume=0;
            }
            [player play];
            [AnimationViewController animateButton:cell.playButton ForDuration:player.duration withColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        }
    } else {

        sender.layer.cornerRadius=sender.frame.size.width/2;

        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:audioData error:nil];
        player.delegate=self;
        [player prepareToPlay];
        if (DISPLAY_IS_MUTED)  {
            player.volume=0;
        }
        [player play];
        [AnimationViewController animateButton:sender ForDuration:player.duration withColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }

}
```

Very simple and very easy, of course. But if I perform an animation on a button in that cell, and then scroll the tableview, it will switch and start animating the wrong cells. It's as if the fact that the superview's frame is changing affect's which button is being animated.
Any advice?

Animation method:

```
+(void)animateButton:(UIButton *)button ForDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration withColor:(UIColor *)color    {
    circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    circle.fillColor = nil;
    circle.lineWidth = button.frame.size.height/2+2;
    circle.strokeColor = color.CGColor;
    circle.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0,    button.frame.size.width/2, button.frame.size.height/2);
    circle.frame= CGRectMake(button.frame.size.width/4, button.frame.size.height/4, button.frame.size.width/2+2, button.frame.size.height/2+2);
    circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:circle.bounds].CGPath;
    [button.layer addSublayer:circle];
    CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.duration            = duration;
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;
    drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    [circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
}
```

Comment: Hey buddy, please show some code

Comment: Your question is little bit vague, are you tapping a button and trying to find that button's superview's indexPath?

Comment: Try to use [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]. Then do animation on main thread

Comment: To use the animation into the right cell you should use the 

    `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` 

method. For use that method you have to adopt the UITableViewDelegate Protocol. Then inside this method you can use the index path for retrive the cell that you need. PS: add the entire code.

Comment: @ mohacs I'm clicking a button in a cell, and the superview shenanigans is my way of figuring out which cell was clicked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you implementing the prepareForReuse method in your cell? There you must stop running animations and reset the state of the cell for the reuse.

From the docs:

prepareForReuse
Prepares a reusable cell for reuse by the table view's delegate.

> If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned
>   from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:. For
>   performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that
>   are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection
>   state. The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
>   should always reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell
>   object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is
>   not called. If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke
>   the superclass implementation.

You need to implement a custom UITableViewCell (create a subclass of it) and implement the prepareForReuse method.

There you can write the logic to stop the animation.

Comment: DisplayPersonTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

Comment: I use that, is that what you mean?

Comment: Here's a link to video recording of the bug. Notice that the first two times you scroll up, it's doesn't do it, but then the third time it starts animating the wrong button. Note: I did not mistaken touch the other button. It did that itself. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-0PXsxLMuw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: You should inplement the prepareForReuse method in a uitableviewcell subclass. That is the place to stop ongoing animations.

Comment: What is happening is that the cell you are animating is reused for other indexpaths while the animation is running

Comment: This is a little complicated, I think. Basically, I have to restart the animation part way through in a different cell to make the animation appear correct in one cell? That doesn't really seem sensible.

Comment: prepareforreuse has no knowledge of the indexPath, which is information I believe I need so I know whether I should "continue" animating

Comment: I update the answer. Do you know how to stop the animation or you need help with that?

Comment: Okay, thank you. Another problem I'm having is that when I animate a cell at an indexPath, it animates cells that are a full screen's distance away as well. Here's a video of the problem:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5tvqlmccvw&feature=youtu.be You can see that I tap a button first, and then scroll upward, and another cell is animating too! Any idea how to fix this? I can post this question in an additional thread if you think that is appropriate

Comment: Yes, you should accept the answer to this question and open a new post for this one to avoid confusion. Try to search for a solution before post, i think it's a common problem.